# Xamarin Android 7+ install APK programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to install an .apk I have downloaded to the downloads folder in Android 7.

I have tried the way recommended in a number of StackOverflow posts and here https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en by using a FileProvider:

```
File file = new File(fileUri);
//using Android.Support.V4.Content;
var downloadUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context,context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".com.package.name.provider", file);
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
install.SetDataAndType(downloadUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.StartActivity(install);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<application android:label="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/myTheme">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.package.name.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." /> 
</paths>
```

The "downloadUri" looks like: "*content://com.package.name.com.package.name.provider/external_files/Download/Sensors%2520Multitool_1.3.0_apk-dl.com.apk*"

The error when the installation window pops up is: **"There was a problem parsing the package"**.

I have installed this package by clicking on it in the downloads folder and it installs fine, I have also tried other .apk's with the same issue.

Comment: Not a guaranteed solution, but maybe you are downloading an apk build for Android O, hence resulting in an parsing exception. Do you have any possibilities to check this?

Comment: I have checked that the apk does install, by just clicking on it in the downloads folder and it does install and run correctly.

Comment: @IulianPopescu You may be onto something, I have tried yet another .apk "es file explorer" just to test if that would work and it did, do you know why apps built for different android versions would not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue in parsing the package was due to the space in the package name "Sensors%2520Multitool_1.3.0_apk-dl.com.apk".

As soon as the space was removed the package installed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

```
File file = new File(fileUri);
if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", toInstall);
    Intent intentS = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
    intentS.SetData(apkUri);
    intentS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    context.StartActivity(intentS);
} else {
    Uri apkUri = Uri.FromFile(toInstall);
    Intent intentS = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intentS.SetDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intentS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    context.StartActivity(intentS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but at the moment I am only targeting android 7+ devices. Once converted into Xamarin I believe this code is the same as mine.