# How to install Apk from app using Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, installation, apk

I am trying to update my app programmatically.

I am able to download the new version of the app apk.

But when the installation code runs nothing happens except an activity that is opened and then closed returning to my app

The installation code is

```
            Java.IO.File apkFile = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/download/" + "com.tri.GOT.apk");

            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;

            var downloadUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.tri.GOT.fileprovider", apkFile);
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
            install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
            install.SetDataAndType(downloadUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            context.StartActivity(install);
```

Comment: I find the same thread about installing apk, that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014498/xamarin-android-7-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFTI tried everything on that thread. Nothing worked. Can Xamarin prompt the installation of a package from the download folder?

Comment: Anything update? Do you solve your issue now?